# Not able to select Java language in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Usually there'll be an option to choose between Kotlin and Java in Android Studio, but now I'm not able to find it and the project opens on Kotlin as default.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwwiw.png)

I tried reinstalling Android Studio by deleting older files and creating new ones. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

select `empty views activity` instead of `empty activity`.

 
[image]

then you will have the option for java
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out ! Could you explain the actual difference between empty activity and empty views activity?

Comment: In the new version, ie flamingo `empty activity` is a composed material 3 template which is recommended as it provides many dynamic colors, and is designed to be cohesive with the new visual style and system UI on Android 12 and above.(note it is based on kotlin)

Comment: @Prajan07 [link](https://youtu.be/41VZhwrXAKI) watch this youtube video for more information regarding Android studio flaminga

Comment: @Prajan07if it finds helpful then please do consider upvoting :)